# How to make element on top on hover (after transition)

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, z-index

i have a problem for css guru I'm not able to untangle.

This is the html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="around">
        <img class="depiction around-depiction"/>
        <div class="label">A label</div>
    </div>
    <div class="around">
        <img class="depiction around-depiction" />
        <div class="label">Another label</div>
    </div>
    ...
    <div class="center">        
        <img class="depiction center-depiction" />
        <div class="label">Center label</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've applied a transform to `.around` element to move in a circle around the `.center` element.

I cannot manage to do two thing :

1. When i hover over an image the image and its label should go above everything (i put a `z-index: 10000` but that doesn't work
2. Make the `.around` image above the .around label. You can see by figure two that hover doesn't work on label div.

This is the css:

```
.container .circle {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: calc(-100px / 2);
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.center {
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}

.depiction {
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.around-depiction:hover {
    transform: scale(4);
    z-index: 1000000;
}

.center-depiction:hover {
    transform: scale(2);
    z-index: 1000000;
}

.label {
    opacity: 0;
    min-width: 200px;
    z-index: -2;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 10px/20px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.center:hover .label,
.around:hover .label {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 5;
}

.center .label:hover,
.around .label:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

[image: hover doesn't go above the transformed elements]
[image: label div blocks hover on image]

Comment: Have you tried using this? `z-index: 1000000 !important;`

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work. Elements not affected by z-index are those with class `.around` those in the circle around central image. They have been set around by a transition with javascript.

Comment: Try changing the `z-index` on the `.circle` elements on hover. And just a note, a `z-index` just have to be higher than the other indexes, at least by `1`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. It doesn't change.

Comment: Try setting `position: relative;` on `.depiction`

Comment: Looks like you probably want `.container{ position:relative; } .container>div{ position:absolute; }`. Then set your `z-index`es.

Comment: Thank you @StackSlave this works. What i was missing is set `z-index` and `position` on the `div` containing the `img`. What i miss now is to have image label under everything before hover. And above everything on hover.

Comment: I solved giving `.label` `pointer-events: none` that's way whatever the `z-indez` the hover will apply on the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the z-index with `position: relative;` on your image/label.
z-index doesn't work on the default, which is `position: static;`

https://coder-coder.com/z-index-isnt-working/